# Error in Safari 4 Beta and Chrome 2

Tags: javascript

I have popup window that is opened through a button click.  If the user searches for a particular item in the child window, I attempt to switch the parent windows location by using window.opener.location in the child window.  The parent window will always stay within the same website.  This works fine in FireFox 3.07 & 3.1 b3, and IE 7&8.  But in Chrome 2.0b (dev branch) and Safari 4 Beta (for Windows) i get this strange error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate a navigation change for frame with URL

Here is the weird thing, in Safari it never works, but in Chrome it works if:

> *Child window is same protocol(HTTP/HTTPS) as the text i am using setting window.opener.location
>   *Parent window and child window are the same protocol(HTTP/HTTPS)

edit: In Opera it only works if both the parent and child window are HTTPS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a cross site scripting security restriction that webkit and opera impliment and IE and FF ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be better to return a value to the parent window that allows it to then redirect to the correct location? That seems cleaner to me.

```
searchterm = window.open(...);
```

Comment: thats a good idea.  let me do some fiddling and see if i can get something that will work.

Comment: from the docs on window.open() the return value is a handle to the window itself.  It would likely be easier to call a function on the opener that does the redirect. e.g. window.opener.funcName('special value'); and the opener window would redirect as needed.

Comment: another limitation i am running in to is cross site scripting...If the child window is HTTPS, and the parent is http, Safari give me an error, and if I try to window.open() it blocks it as a popup.